# Flex set CSS class at runtime

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I know how to set individual style names to a UI component but what is the way to set set the CSS class itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uicomponent.setStyle("styleName", undefined);
```

Do some thing like this hope will help.[For further reference please refer this link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/18/setting-a-flex-applications-style-name/)